# How is it possible to have 102% indicated?

Tags: aircraft-performance

Watching some videos, I noticed that an sr22 was showing 102% power on takeoff. How is this possible?

Comment: What is "your plane" in this context? What are you looking at to see "102% power"? An N1 indicator? (Questions already address that.) Something else? Very unclear.

Comment: Just in general. I've seen it in sr22 and turbines with n1.

Comment: I watched some videos where the Cirrus sr22 was showing 102% power on takeoff. Why is this?

Comment: Because the engine was running at 102% power, I guess. Is your question "How is it possible to exceed 100%?"

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how that's possible.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to ask how it's possible to exceed 100%, and maybe it will be reopened.

Comment: If you are wondering how this is possible you may want to reference a similar example here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hW008FcKr3Q

Comment: If you are hired to work 40 hours/week, but one week you work 10 hours of overtime, i.e. a total of 50 hours/week, then how many % of your contractually agreed time have you worked that week?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"100%" is a relative number and its not uncommon in aircraft engines to see higher than "100%" operations published. Often "100%" is the *maximum **continuous** operation setting* or some other relative power limitation. Manufacturers will test and certify their engines with other limitations like "102% for XX minutes" or similar limitations. This means you can run the engine at some given (high) power setting for a fixed amount of time ***safely*** but ***not*** indefinitely at that setting.